# How can I check if a local variable exists?

Tags: c#, variables

Maybe this question sounds strange for C# programmers, but there's a way (or good way) to check if a local variable exists? For example (not a real code, but to it´s just to show the context):

```
TagBuilder name = new TagBuilder("span");
name.InnerHtml.Append("John");
if (Session.IsMaster()) {
    TabBuilder container = new TagBuilder("label");
    container.InnerHtml.Append("Our Master of Universe, ");
    container.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(name);
}


return var_exists(container)? container : name;
```

Is it possible to do in C#? Or there´s an another way to do this?

Comment: Probably possible, but this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/176054) - what are you trying to do?

Comment: The code you've written simply won't compile - you can't use a variable outside its scope. You could declare it earlier, set it to a non-null value in the `if` block and then check whether it's null later... personally I'd just return inside the `if` block, or return *before* the `if` block if Session isn't master instead.

Comment: in a compiled language as c# (and many, if not every, other compiled language), if you use a variable that "does not exists" you get a compiler error, so no need to check it exists at runtime, and that's why c# does not includ your suggested `var_exists` statement/method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should move the declaration of `container` out of the `if-block`, so it can be used outside of the block:

```
TagBuilder name = new TagBuilder("span");
name.InnerHtml.Append("John");

TabBuilder container = null;
if (Session.IsMaster()) {
    container = new TagBuilder("label");
    container.InnerHtml.Append("Our Master of Universe, ");
    container.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(name);
}

return container ?? name;
```

`??` is the null coalescing operator which can be interpreted as:

```
container != null ? container : name
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks so much.